# ng-repeat inside another ng-repeat - updating on a http service call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of posts and each of them has comments associated. I have separate web services for listing of posts and the comments. So I do this:

```
 <li class="timeline-item" ng-repeat="post in controller.myposts">
                                <div class="panel panel-white">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="timeline-item-header">
                                            <img src="{{post.userImageURL}}" style="height: 50px" alt="">
                                            <p>{{post.userName}} <span>Posted a Status</span></p>
                                            <small>{{post.created}}</small>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="timeline-item-post">
                                            <p>{{post.message}}</p>
                                            <div class="timeline-options">
                                                <a href="#"><i class="icon-like"></i> Like (7)</a>
                                                <a href="#"><i class="icon-bubble"></i> Comment (2)</a>
                                                <a href="#"><i class="icon-share"></i> Share (3)</a>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="margin-bottom-20">
                                            <a class="cursor-pointer" ng-click="controller.loadPreviousComments(post.id)">view previous comments</a><br>
                                            </div>
                                            {{post.comments}}
                                            <div class="timeline-comment" ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
                                                <div class="timeline-comment-header">
                                                    <img src="/assets/images/avatar5.png" alt="" onerror="this.src='/assets/images/avatar1.png''">
                                                    <p>Nick Doe <small>1 hour ago</small></p>
                                                </div>
                                                <p class="timeline-comment-text">Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Reply"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
```

When here is my controller:

```
 this.loadPreviousComments = function(messageId,limit){
        var limit = limit || 5;
        $http.get('/api/v2/communitycomments',{params:{messageId:messageId,items:limit}})
            .success(function(data){
               that.myposts.comments = data.message;
            });
    }
```

It doesn't work because of obvious reasons: i update the myposts.comments in the controller which isn't available as a child scope of individual posts.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the whole post when loading the comments:

html:

```
<a class="cursor-pointer" ng-click="controller.loadPreviousComments(post)">view previous comments</a>
```

controller:

```
// Takes a 'message' as parameter instead of just the id
this.loadPreviousComments = function (message, limit){
    var limit = limit || 5;
    var params = {
        messageId: message.id,
        items: limit
    };

    $http.get('/api/v2/communitycomments', { params: params })
        .success(function (data){
            // Add older comments to existing ones
            message.comments = (message.comments || []).concat(data.message);
        });
}
```

Comment: This works but my orderBy: comment.modified:true stopped working ! Comments need to be ordered by date

Comment: Where is your orderBy? how does it look like?